In Python Flask new project, cannot Activate the environment as per official doc
I'm new to Python Flask. Here is my terminal commands as per official flask doc.
Official flask link: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/stable/installation/
WORK/2025/Python 
[08:45]❯ cd FlaskIntro/

2025/Python/FlaskIntro 
[08:45]❯ python3 -m venv .venv

2025/Python/FlaskIntro 
[08:46]❯ . .venv/bin/activate
.venv/bin/activate (line 40): “case” builtin not inside of switch block
case "$(uname)" in
^~~^
from sourcing file .venv/bin/activate
.: Error while reading file '.venv/bin/activate'

2025/Python/FlaskIntro 
[08:46]❯ python --version
Python 3.13.1

2025/Python/FlaskIntro 
[08:46]❯ python3 --version
Python 3.13.1

2025/Python/FlaskIntro 
[08:46]❯ 

SOLUTION: ❯ . .venv/bin/activate.fish

I tried all the files and found that I was using fish shell.


2025/Python/FlaskIntro 
[09:20]❯ python3 -m venv .venv

2025/Python/FlaskIntro 
[09:20]❯ . .venv/bin/activate.fish 

2025/Python/FlaskIntro [ v3.13.1(.venv)]
[09:21]❯ pip install Flask
Collecting Flask
  Downloading flask-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)

I tried all the files in venv/bin folder and the above command worked.
Cause of the problem: I was using fish shell.
